# How to determine if my mail server is configured correctly?

Tags: smtp, dns, email

Does anyone know of an online service (similar to the ones that tell you if a site is up or down) that can connect to a specified mail server and perform checks to see if it is configured correctly?

If not, does anyone know exactly what these checks should be? (https://www.nearlyfreespeech.net/about/email gives an interesting stance, but looks to be not very specific)

The specific mail server I'm trying to see if it is configured properly is mx.adammw111.co.cc , but I'd rather find a automatic checker *outside* my own network than do many manual checks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that you want to check for whether your mail server will act as a open relay (a bad thing) then you can use the online checker located here http://www.abuse.net/relay.html.  Just put in your mail server IP address and leave the other options blank.

You can also try http://www.mxtoolbox.com/ to provide the extra header checks and SPF records.

Comment: Well, those checks check out, but I was looking for ones that test that the DNS records and verification are set correctly as well. For example, some servers that send incorrect headers in the mail or if the reverse DNS doesn't match, they may be marked as spam.

Comment: I have also added a link for http://www.mxtoolbox.com/.  Please mark this question as answered and upmark my reply if it is of use.

Comment: The service at the first link seems to have been discontinued.

Comment: and if you don't know how to fix, here is a comprehensive article (at least about DKIM, SPF, DMARC): https://dmarcly.com/blog/how-to-implement-dmarc-dkim-spf-to-stop-email-spoofing-phishing-the-definitive-guide#what-is-dmarc

Answer (score 1):

http://www.intodns.com/ will give you interesting information about your mail server (linked to your domain name)

Consider http://www.monitis.com for monitoring.